# RxJava2: Converts callbacks sequence dependencies to RxJava2

Tags: rx-java2

I have two legacy classes A and B, both of them need to set a callback and then execute it by calling the execute() function. The onSuccess() will be called if the execution succeeds and onError() is called otherwise. However, the execution of Class B depends on the execution result of Class A. The following is the code snippet.

I know how to convert each of A and B to Observable, thus I wrote an asObservable() function. But, I don't know how to combine them with the sequence of A to B. Anyone knows how to do it, thanks.

```java
package rxjava2.exercise.com.example;

import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.ObservableEmitter;
import io.reactivex.ObservableOnSubscribe;
import io.reactivex.ObservableSource;
import io.reactivex.Observer;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;
import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;
import io.reactivex.functions.Function;

public class RxJava2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.setCallback(new A.ACallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final String text) {
                final B b = new B(text);
                b.setCallback(new B.BCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int result) {
                        System.out.println(result);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {

                    }
                });
                b.execute();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }
        });
        a.execute();
    }

    static class A {

        private ACallback mCallback;

        void setCallback(ACallback callback) {
            mCallback = callback;
        }

        void execute() {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mCallback.onSuccess("5566");
                }
            }).start();
        }

        public interface ACallback {
            void onSuccess(String text);
            void onError();
        }

        Observable<String> asObservable() {
            return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
                @Override
                public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<String> emitter) throws Exception {
                    setCallback(new ACallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String text) {
                            emitter.onNext(text);
                            emitter.onComplete();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            emitter.onError(new IllegalArgumentException());
                        }
                    });
                    execute();
                }
            });
        }

    }

    static class B {

        private BCallback mCallback;
        private String mText;

        B(String text) {
            mText = text;
        }

        void setCallback(BCallback callback) {
            mCallback = callback;
        }

        void execute() {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mCallback.onSuccess(Integer.parseInt(mText + 7788));
                }
            }).start();
        }

        interface BCallback {
            void onSuccess(int result);
            void onError();
        }

        Observable<Integer> asObservable() {
            return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<Integer> emitter) throws Exception {
                    setCallback(new B.BCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(int result) {
                            emitter.onNext(result);
                            emitter.onComplete();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            emitter.onError((new IllegalArgumentException()));
                        }
                    });
                    execute();
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlatMap the `Observable` of A into B's `Observable`:

```
A a = ...

a.asObservable()
.flatMap(text -> new B(text).asObservable())
.subscribe(b -> { /* ... */ }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```